# Simple If Statement issue with Python

Tags: python, if-statement

Can you guys point out the problem when using "if" repetitively in the codes, for example:

```
if x == 2:
    do something
if x == 3:
    do something
if x == 4:
    do something
```

Thanks

Comment: Why do you think there's a problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208/replacements-for-switch-case-statement-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will not cause any errors.  Whether you use `if` or `elif` will depend on your purpose.  Sometimes you want to check several things that are not related.  For example, you might have something like

```
if action is None:
    action = DEFAULT_ACTION
if args is None:
    args = ()
```

Whether or not `action` is `None` will not effect your decision to check if `args` is `None`.  You might have something else, however, where it makes a difference.  For example:

```
if action is ACTION_JUMP:
    action_jump()
elif distance > 4:
    action_run(distance)
```

In this case, you don't want `action_run()` to be called unless the action is not `ACTION_JUMP`.  What you use simply depends on your purpose.

Answer (score -2):

> > > x
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >           x
> > >       NameError: name 'x' is not defined

If you just assign sth. to x, this won't make errors, but picture:
You want sb. input 1-5, but he might input 6. You need to add "else". But you just used so many "if".
I recommend using "if---elif(else)---else".